# What software can I use to manager my video lessons?

Tags: windows-7, linux, podcasts

I have a lot of different MIT lectures downloaded from youtube. I have also an account on lynda.com.

I would like to find a software to manage all the data, like a podcast software. Maybe there is something with annotation function, so I can edit my classes and put notes (cut video snippets?). The most important feature would be a downloader, because I prefer to download MIT lectures from youtube and watch them later. Screenshots/slides/other data should be saved in the lecture folder.

My OS is Linux Mint
(win/raspberry pi ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux  there's only 1 downloader that i know of, youtube-dl
On windows there are many downloaders such as ytd downloader.

I don't know of any video manager + youtube downloader in the same software, but creating playlists and so forth is feasible using any video manager such as vlc.

Comment: youtube-dl.py is on windows too.(command line of course).

Answer (score 1):

**Grab your research with a single click**.

> **A personal research assistant.**
>
> Zotero is the only research tool that automatically senses content in
>   your web browser, allowing you to add it to your personal library with
>   a single click. Whether you're searching for a preprint on arXiv.org,
>   a journal article from JSTOR, a news story from the New York Times, or
>   a book from your university library catalog, Zotero has you covered
>   with support for thousands of sites.
>
> **Store anything.**
>
> Zotero collects all your research in a single, searchable interface.
>   You can add PDFs, images, audio and video files, snapshots of web
>   pages, and really anything else. Zotero automatically indexes the
>   full-text content of your library, enabling you to find exactly what
>   you're looking for with just a few keystrokes.

[Zotero](http://www.zotero.org/) Works with [Windows, Mac, Linux and Firefox, Chrome, Safari](http://www.zotero.org/download/).

I used this in college and it made connecting all the different forms of data super easy once I understood the functionality and layout. They have videos and documented tutorials of almost everything you could do.